# extruding faces along normals are distorded

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to extrude using  the extrude faces along normal, and also trying make a simple E, then S + shift Z to scale on X and Y axis, but its not extruding inwards uniformly. on the cube mesh, its working, but on the more complex model its looking incorrect.

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have scale applied (`Ctrl+A > scale`) in object mode. Also, make sure you normals are all facing out by selecting the whole mesh in edit mode, then `mesh > normals > recalculate outside`. If none of that works, make sure you have no dupes by doing a merge by distance.

Comment: Hi Christopher. I tried everything you mentioned, and still get the awkward result. I also noticed when extruding on a mesh which is not scaled inwards, the result is better, but I have noticed that some of the lines tend to curve and others are straight although its just a cube mesh. https://ibb.co/pbScpHT
https://ibb.co/Z6VLftv

Comment: https://ibb.co/S7xMkS4

Comment: Yeah, that's strange. There must be something else going on, but I don't think I can explain it, I'm afraid.

Comment: I also uploaded a recent example today, in case you missed it, with further more explanation.

Comment: in addition to  christopher's solution , try to hit "a" and "m" and select "by distance" before try to extrude , also you migh have extra faces inside your geometry , which in resault of wrong modeling , try to delete them by hitting "alt + z" and selecting those faces

Comment: The normals have a lot of different angles at the corners. The Extrude is trying to compensate those angles in a common direction resulting in weird shapes. You can go to Viewport Overlays and enable the Measurement > Edge Angle to see those different angles at the corners.